# map and lambda function not doubling list elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried using the map and lambda functions in conjunction to double each integer element in a list and then print the list but it has no effect on the list and prints the original list itself.
Following is the code snippet:

```
lis=[1,2,3,4]
map(lambda x:x*2,lis)
print(lis)
```

The output comes out to be the original list itself i.e. [1,2,3,4]

Comment: the result fromt the call to map is not asigned to anything -> lost in the void

Answer (score 4, accepted):

map doesn't mutate the actual list, it simply creates a new iterable object with the function applied.

What you want to do then is

```
lis = list(map(lambda x: x*2, lis))
```

Answer (score 1):

That's expected, as map creates a new sequence and does not modify the original list in-place.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `map()` returns a new list and doesn't change the original list. So you should assign the result.

```
lis=[1,2,3,4]
newlis = map(lambda x:x*2, lis)
print(newlis)
```